# Relação entre tabela A e B retorna erro porque chama dados da tabela C no CakePhP

Tags: cakephp-2, modelo-relacional

Estou a 3 dias batendo cabeça com um problema: Eu tenho algumas tabelas no sistema e esse erro acontece nas telas mais improváveis.

Vou dar o exemplo mais recente:

> 2015-03-13 16:37:51 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'CadRepresentante.id' in 'field list'
>   Request URL: /lhasa/auxiliar/situacao_banco/editar/18 
>   #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\lhasa\app\Controller\SituacaoBancoController.php(87):
>   Model->read(NULL, '18')
>   #9 [internal function]: SituacaoBancoController->auxiliar_editar('18')

A tabela AuxSituacaoBanco tem ligação $hasMany com CadProposta, mas nenhuma ligação com CadRepresentante!
Se eu remover a ligação com CadProposta no model de AuxSituacaoBanco, para de dar o erro de edição, mas ai em CadProposta que, possui ligação $belongsTo, começa a dar erro da AuxSituacaoBanco.

Já não sei mais o que fazer para resolver esse problema!

AuxSituacaoBanco:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'CadProposta' => array(
        'className' => 'CadProposta',
        'foreignKey' => 'aux_situacao_banco_id',
    )
);
```

CadProposta

```
public $belongsTo = array(
...
    'AuxSituacaoBanco' => array(
        'className' => 'AuxSituacaoBanco',
        'foreignKey' => 'aux_situacao_banco_id',
    ),
...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou ai mas provavelmente o model CadProposta deve ter uma associação belongsTo com CadRepresentante

```php
'CadRepresentante' => array(
        ....
)
```

adiciona essa linha

```
'CadRepresentante' => array(
       'fields' => array('CadRepresentante.id'),
)
```

Tem uma outra coisa que você fazer se você não precisa dos dados de proposta na edição da AuxSituacaoBanco na primeira linha da função edit dentro do controller você pode deixar a recursividade do model em -1 dessa forma ele não buscara dados de nenhum relacionamento.
$this->AuxSituacaoBanco->recursive = -1;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive